What happens if you isolate an inductor from a live circuit?
Suppose you have a capacitor and you charge it with a battery until it has a voltage V. You suddenly disconnect the capacitor from the battery. As far as I know, the capacitor keeps with voltage V until you discharge it, storing energy in the form of electric field. Ok.
Now suppose you have an inductor connected to a battery with a stable current flowing trough it. Suddenly, the battery dies, creating an infinitely insulating environment between the two inductor terminals.
Now we have energy stored in the form of magnetic field in the coil, but electric current can't flow in the coil since there is nowhere for the charge to flow. The magnetic field cannot be sustained since there is no stable current.
What happens then?
I can imagine an electric arch happening to discharge because of the hysteresis effect, but what if I consider the infinitely insulating environment? Does it even make any sense to consider this kind of environment?
